# Getting Fine Code Coverage results for project which has hides full path to code in stack traces

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, code-coverage

I am using:
IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current : Version 17.1.3
FCC version: 1.1.192

---

I have two projects:

**MyProject** and **MyProjectTests**

**MyProject** contains a series of classes using the **MyProject** namespace
**MyProjectTests** contains a series of tests using the **MyProject.tests** namespace

This essentially mimics the example I've seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rae5bTE2D3o
All tests are passing that I have written to date.
**MyProject** has been setup to exclude full path from stack trace entries by adding
**$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))=./** to the **PropertyGroup** block as per https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/402742/how-can-we-avoid-showing-the-literal-path-in-the-exceptions-stack-trace

---

When I look at the Output windows when running, I see the following:

`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Managers/SettingsManager.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Managers/BackupManager.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Utilities/LoggerCallerEnrichmentConfiguration.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Constants.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Managers/SettingsManager.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Controls/AboutBox.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Controls/AboutBox.Designer.cs' does not exist (any more).`
`2023-05-30T12:54:58: File './Controls/ContentBrowser.cs' does not exist (any more).`

For all of the files in my project under test. This suggests FCC doesn't know where to look for the files under test referenced in **MyProject.dll**.

In my **MyProjectTests** project I can see a path:  bin\Debug\net6.0-windows which appears to contain all the usual artifacts (ie exes, dlls) including **MyProject.dll** from my project under tests as well as test aritfacts.
It also contains bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\fine-code-coverage\coverage-tool-output\MyProjectTests-fcc-mscodecoverage-generated.runsettings which when I look, has the following settings related to code coverage:

`<DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" enabled="True">`
  `<Configuration>`
    `<CodeCoverage>`
      `<ModulePaths>`
        `<Exclude>`
          `<ModulePath>C:\\Users\\Matt27\\repos\\MyProjectTests\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\MyProjectTests.dll</ModulePath>`
        `</Exclude>`
      `<Include>`
        `<ModulePath>.*\\MyProject.dll$</ModulePath>`
      `</Include>`
    `</ModulePaths>`

---

If I remove the entry **$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))=./** from the **PropertyGroup** block and run the tests, I get full coverage results for **MyProject**.

So my question is essentially: is there a way to leave **$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))=./** in the **PropertyGroup** block - as it is essential that the full path to files in the stack trace is not shared and still be able to get coverage results.

As per description above, I can get coverage to work by modifying project config to add full path to files in stack traces, but this is not a viable option for production.

I am hoping there is a setting somewhere that can be made either in the project settings of **MyProject** or by explictly telling FCC where to look for files.

I do not have a standalone PDB file, this is built into main binaries.
The pathmap change I made I want to keep as it provides good detials on line number of issues without displaying full path of build machine.